# How to make SnakeYAML to serialise objects without explicit annotations?

Tags: kotlin, yaml, snakeyaml

I made `to_yaml` function for the SnakeYAML but it doesn't print the YAML, it prints instead `!!Portfolio {}`. The code

```
fun to_yaml(v: Any): String {
  val yaml = Yaml()
  val writer = StringWriter()
  yaml.dump(v, writer)
  return writer.toString()
}
```

How to update it so it would **print any object as just a key/value collection**, like JSON for JS object?

**Without the need to specially annotate that class**? Also, ideally avoid print the class name, only the content of the object, just like how JSON works in JavaScript.

## Example

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import java.io.StringWriter


fun to_yaml(v: Any): String {
  val yaml = Yaml()
  val writer = StringWriter()
  yaml.dump(v, writer)
  return writer.toString()
}


fun main() {

  val portfolio = Portfolio(
    "id1",
    listOf(
      PortfolioPosition(
        1,
        1.0,
        PortfolioStockContract(
          "MSFT"
        )
      )
    )
  )
  println(to_yaml(portfolio))
}
    
class Portfolio(
  val account_id: String,
  val positions:  List<PortfolioPosition>
)

class PortfolioPosition (
  val position:     Int,
  val average_cost: Double,
  val contract:     PortfolioContract
)

interface PortfolioContract

enum class ContractType { stock, option }

class PortfolioStockContract (
  val symbol:   String
) : PortfolioContract {
  val type = ContractType.stock
}
```

Comment: You can try using `@JvmField` on the properties. As for the root tag, use `yaml.dumpAs(v, Tag.MAP)`.

Comment: @flyx thanks, but I would like to avoid that and keep the code clean.

Comment: Then I suggest having a look at [kaml](https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/kaml/) which does use SnakeYAML but has a Kotlin-native API.

Comment: @flyx actually it uses SnakeYAML engine, it's in its dependencies, it seems to be just a wrapper/adapter around it

Comment: Yes, that's what I said :)

Comment: @flyx true, I read it wrongly, sorry :). But it seems like it requires some sort of annotations like `@Serializable`. Anyway will check it, thanks.